# How to read notation about little o notation

Tags: terminology, asymptotics

On page 2 of [this pdf](http://kisonecat.com/teaching/2009/ibl-analysis/little-oh.pdf) the author introduces this equivalence relation:

$$f(x) \sim_{x_0} g(x) \iff f(x) - g(x) = o(x-x_0)\quad \text{as } x\to x_0$$

Assuming this is a standard notation, how does one read $f(x) \sim_{x_0} g(x)$?  As in, what should the blank be in "f of x is [blank] g of x"?

Comment: It reads ‘equivalent in the neighbourhood of $x_0$’. Unfortunately this definition is false: it should be $o(g(x))$ on the right hand side (intuitively, it means, if $g(x)\ neq 0$ for $x\neq x_0$, that $\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}\to 1$ as $x\to x_0$).

Comment: @Bernard: I first thought like you, but the author of the pdf defines $\sim_{x_0}$ as in the OP's post and does not claim that this is the usual equivalence relation for functions.

Comment: Then it is not the standard equivalence – unless there's a typo.